# How to perform an execute command using a JSON variable?

Tags: php, json, variables, exec

I've got a JSON variable ($epoch) which contains the date in epoch (1370777177), and I'd like to convert it to the following format and output it:

```
date "+%F %R" -ud @1370777177
```

which returns:

```
2013-06-09 11:26
```

So I figure using php to echo the command is one way to do it. Is there a way to convert the epoch to the format above  and append it to a DIV using JS? That might be a lot easier. I've tried creating a PHP variable which encodes the JSON var:

```
$date = json_encode($epoch);
echo exec ('date "+%F %R" -ud @%date');
```

But that doesn't work.

```
echo json_encode($epoch)
```

returns 'null'. The JSON variable is in a external .js file.

Comment: What is the contents of `$epoch`? Is it actually json encoded string?

Comment: Well it's just the number 1370777177. It's from an API using getJSON. I hope this helps.

Comment: If its just a number, you wont need to decode it. You should just be able to do this. `echo exec ("date "+%F %R" -ud @$date");`. But you should do the date conversion with php `date` function. Using exec is slower had has injection issues.

Comment: Do you mean `echo exec ("date "+%F %R" -ud @$epoch");`? If I shouldn't need to decode, I shouldn't need the `$date` variable, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to convert the epoch to the format above and append it to a DIV using JS?

Yes, there is.

Also exec() will scale awesomely.

Comment: good to hear, yaccz. can you tell  me more about converting epoch to DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS in JS?

Comment: 1. What you call epoch is not epoch. It's the number of seconds since epoch.

Comment: Oh right, so it's just a matter of dividing the seconds into days, months and years, then?